# window.onbeforeunload not firing in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, mozilla

I have an app where I need to see if the user is online/offline.
I've used onbeforeunload event to check whether they close the page, but when I refresh the page in Firefox, it doesn't get caught.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        socket.emit('leave', {'username': username, 'channel': channel});
    };
```

It works alright in Chrome

Comment: Are you sure the event is not fired? Can you try to set a random value in the localStorage for instance to verify? The best in your case would be to use the sendBeacon API, which can proceed with the request even after the page is dead, but not sure how that should be done with your ws setup.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. It only fires if I add a return statement after emitting and only if I interacted with the page beforehand.

Comment: If I just hit F5 without clicking anything, it wont fire

Comment: Well... I'm sorry but if I go to [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dur9w7my/) on my FF76, without clicking anywhere, then reload the page, I get a new random number logged everytime -> the event fires.

Comment: Yeah, seems to fire but it doesn't emit back to my server. So the problem is in emitting

Comment: Yes that's why you need to use the sendBeacon API, as I told you in my first comment...